# In a Blank Webots World, How to Operate the Mavic

Tags: mapping, webots, ardrone-autonomy, drone, c

I need to operate the mavic drone in a world other than its demonstration but when I do so the robot will just crash to the ground. I thought it was the world parameters or the controller that was different from the simulation but even after changing it continues to turn around when starting. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested in 2023a and 2023b and the only change that has been necessary in Worldinfo is to set the timestep to 8 and a linear damping to 0.5 and angular 0.5